# Are there any mantras or sadhanas that enable one to remember the current birth in the next birth?

Tags: mantras, sadhana

How can we ensure remembrance of all knowledge gained in current birth in the next birth if moksha is not achieved?

Comment: Swami Vivekananda mentions a tapasya for 12 years unbroken, that will ensure recollection of previous birth. Check out his Complete Works.

Comment: @mar Please specify which chapter in which volume.